# Azure Log Analytics (Kusto) Convert from hex

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to convert from hex in Kusto? I see a scalar function to convert to hex, but I want to convert from hex.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/tohexfunction

Answer (score 1):

you can use hex value for long literal, for example:

print long(0x123)

see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/long

Comment: I don't think that works as expected. For example 0x22 converts to a value of 34. I would like the value returned in ASCII.

Comment: Conversion from hex to ascii is not supported. Please open an [Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer) 
 item

Answer (score 1):

(Posting to old thread if anyone finds this in the future.)

```
let T = datatable(Value:string) [
'A2FF',
'BEAD',
'CAFE',
'FACE',
'C0C0'
];
T
| extend ValueExtracted = extract_all('(.)', reverse(Value))
| mv-expand ValueExtracted
| serialize 
| extend ValueIndex = indexof('0123456789ABCDEF', ValueExtracted, 0)
| extend ValuePow = row_number(0, prev(Value) != Value)
| extend ValueDig = pow(16, ValuePow) * ValueIndex 
| summarize ValueComplete = sum(ValueDig) by Value 
| extend ToHexCalc = tohex(toint(ValueComplete))
```

Granted it isn't pretty but it seems to work for at least this data set.  An inbuit function would be so much better I agree.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/tohexfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/indexoffunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/rownumberfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/powfunction

Output:

```
[Value, ValueComplete, ToHexCalc
A2FF, 41727, a2ff
BEAD, 48813, bead
CAFE, 51966, cafe
FACE, 64206, face
C0C0, 49344, c0c0][1]
```

Comment: While the effort is appreciated, this does not answer the question and should be deleted. P.S. there is much simpler way to achieve hex to dec conversion: `print hex = 'A2FF' | extend dec = toint(strcat('0x',hex))`

Answer (score 0):

Arriving late to the party...

[0x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/long)
[tolong()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tolongfunction)
[make_string()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makestringfunction)

```
print character = make_string(tolong('0x22'))
```

| character |
| --- |
| " |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUUjOSCxKTC5JLVKwVchNzE6NLy4BiqdrlOTn5AMpdYMKIyN1TU0AqcrIWi0AAAA=)